# How can I pass all the filenames in a directory as an argument to a command in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, command-line

I'm using Subliminal (a tool to find subtitles for any given media file) to get the subtitles for a bunch of TV series episodes, and right now, I'm doing it manually, for every single episode. It's a tedious process. Instead, I'd like to automate it using Bash.

Me not being a Bash-ninja, tried this first:

```
for i in /dir/*.avi; do subliminal -l en -- "$i"; done;
```

But obviously, that didn't work.

subliminal also accepts multiple filenames as parameters, so the following works as well:

```
subliminal -l en -- file1.avi file2.avi ... filen.avi
```

But it's quite a lot of work to manually type and tab-complete every file name. I figured there'd be some easier way to accomplish this? Maybe using xargs, but I'm not sure.

What are your ideas?

Comment: To store names in an array: `files=( /dir/*.avi )` -- and then you can expand them: `subliminal -l en -- "${files[@]}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wildcards expand before the command is run.

```
subliminal -l en -- file*.avi
```

Comment: Awesome, that's just what I wanted. But for future reference, how would I pass the entire list of filenames (with no specific pattern anywhere) as multiple arguments to a command?

Comment: You could cat or echo it to xargs.

Comment: `ls *.avi | xargs cat ...`? Could you show an example? I'm not really familiar with xargs yet.

Comment: You would never use ls for this. `subliminal ... *.avi` `cat listoffiles.txt | xargs subliminal ...` `xargs subliminal ... <<< "${arrayoffiles[@]}"`

Comment: Safer to NUL-delimit: `printf '%s\0' *.avi >list-of-files; cat list-of-files | xargs -0 subliminal -l en --`

Comment: @JosephJohn What do you mean by "the entire list" of filenames? If you want to pass in all files in a directory regardless of their name, you still use a glob pattern: `*` alone matches all files in the directory.

Comment: @thatotherguy: "If you want to pass in all files in a directory regardless of their name" - Exactly that :)